# How to find all basic blocks appearing between two specific basic blocks in LLVM IR level?

Tags: c++, graph, llvm

I am doing some analysis in `LLVM` and for some reasons I want to find all basic blocks that can be executed between two specific basic blocks.

For example, assume that we have two basic blocks named `A` and `B`. Now I want to know which basic blocks can appear after executing basic block `A` and before basic block `B`.

One possible solution is using the reachability analysis of control glow graph. For example, if basic block `C` is reachable from `A` and also basic block `B` is reachable from `C`, then we can say `C` can be executed after `A` and before `B`.

The only thing that I could find in the LLVM was this function in `llvm/analysis/CFG.h`:

```
/// Determine whether instruction 'To' is reachable from 'From', without passing
/// through any blocks in ExclusionSet, returning true if uncertain.
///
/// Determine whether there is a path from From to To within a single function.
/// Returns false only if we can prove that once 'From' has been executed then
/// 'To' can not be executed. Conservatively returns true.
///
/// This function is linear with respect to the number of blocks in the CFG,
/// walking down successors from From to reach To, with a fixed threshold.
/// Using DT or LI allows us to answer more quickly. LI reduces the cost of
/// an entire loop of any number of blocks to be the same as the cost of a
/// single block. DT reduces the cost by allowing the search to terminate when
/// we find a block that dominates the block containing 'To'. DT is most useful
/// on branchy code but not loops, and LI is most useful on code with loops but
/// does not help on branchy code outside loops.
bool isPotentiallyReachable(
     const Instruction *From, const Instruction *To,
     const SmallPtrSetImpl<BasicBlock *> *ExclusionSet = nullptr,
     const DominatorTree *DT = nullptr, const LoopInfo *LI = nullptr);
```

But the problem is that this function is so conservative and the answers are not certain. I want to know the certain answers.

Answer (score 1):

The concept you're looking for is called domination. You want the blocks that are dominated by A and postdominated by B. For this, you make or obtain a [DominatorTree](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1DominatorTree.html) and a [PostDominatorTree](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1PostDominatorTree.html), and look at the parts of the trees that are below A and B. You can obtain one from the pass managers, if you're writing a pass.

However, note that LLVM's code is conservative because this sort of thing tends to become complicated in a hurry. What about blocks that are executed after A (ie. dominated by A) but that return or throw an exception instead of branching to B? Do you want those? What if there's an infinite loop? Those can be intentional. What if an exception might be thrown and the handler isn't postdominated by B? This sort of thing is full of cases you have to think about.

Comment: I think I have not been super clear. If a block `A` dominates a block like `C`, it means that every path from entry block to `C` should go through block `A`. But in my case, it is enough to there be only one path from `A` to `C`. Domination is stronger than what I am looking for.

Comment: One other solution is to find all paths from `A` to `B` and see what blocks appear in these paths. But I tried this and it is so complex and time consuming.

Comment: It's easy to build sets of the blocks that are reachable from A using the llvm::successors() iterator and the ones that can reach B using the llvm::predecessors() iterator. Then you just take a set intersection.

Comment: You are right! Now I am iterating all successors of block `A` and repeat this until I reach block `B`. In my specific problem I am sure I will reach `B` and I will not be trapped in infinite loops. Thanks for reminding me of this simple solution :) .